# Looking for a resource/advice on how I can improve my cursive given these constraints (handwriting sample included):

Tags: script, handwriting

I am an engineer who does a large amount of cross-disciplinary work in mathematics and scientific computing. Attached is a sample of my handwriting:

[image]

My handwriting has been developed largely "out of my head" without any reference to an established script. My understanding of penmanship and scripts is purely amateurish, with me having read no literature on the subject. My handwriting is geared to satisfy the following criteria:

1. Topological connectivity of words: Within fields like mathematics, and scientific computing, there tend to be objects (including functions) that need to be distinct from each other and easy to read and differentiate. Within programming languages, words and objects are distinguished by what I perceive as careful typesetting and whitespace usage. This is nearly impossible to accomplish when casually writing quickly with pen or pencil. However, cursive is highly advantageous to this end, as any word I want can be written connectively. To that end, I've attempted to make all letters in the Roman alphabet connectable (including capitals). I have also tried to include connectible variations of numbers and Greek letters, although work in this domain hasn't been wholly satisfied.
2. Characters are distinguished by "features" and " relative orientation" rather than "size" or "scale". In other words, a letter is not distinguished from another letter by being "bigger" than the other.
3. All characters are distinct from one another. For instance, there must be defining features between a cursive "w" and two "l" characters in succession. There can be no contextual difference in size.
4. Characters are relatively compact and easy to write, with it being "hard" to make mistakes that make characters impossible or contextual to distinguish. That is, even if I write "quickly" or sloppily, there are certain "landmarks" that make my letters possible to distinguish.
   The emphasis then is less on beauty and more on functionality. There is however a bias to interpretability and clarity over speed. I am interested in scripts that accomplish this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about learning handwriting and not about writing in the sense of authoring texts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user52445 Questions about handwriting techniques are perfectly on-topic here, as far as I can discern. I see no reason this should be closed.

Comment: @F1Krazy The topic of this site, as I understand it, is the composition of written works (OED *write*, meaning III.), not the delineation of lettershapes on a surface (OED *write*, meaning II.). The latter would much better fit the context of graphic design or arts & crafts, for which there are dedicated SE sites. I understand that handwriting questions have been allowed on this site, but to me learning how to inscribe characters on a surface has nothing to do with learning how to narrate a story, and the mere polysemy of the word *writing* shouldn't be a reason for the inclusion of the first.

Comment: In fact, the confusion of the several meanings of the word *writing* are one common cause for the troubles that many aspiring writers face: They assume that writing a narrartive should be easy because they have mastered written language (i.e. they "can write"). And this misconception blocks them from approaching writing as a skill that requires as much diligent training as any other skill.

Comment: @user52445 If you think the scope of the site should be changed to disallow handwriting questions, then that's something to discuss on [Meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/). As you say, though, handwriting questions have been allowed here before, so for the time being, I'm simply following precedent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn to write clearly and in an even style, approach learning to write like a first grader: train the basic shapes of the script you want to learn first, and then develop the individual letter shapes one after another (or group by group) from that. I'd advise you to get a first grade book for each script you want to aquire.

Example for "swinging exercises" from a German book:

[image]

Here is a video course teaching "basic strokes" for cursive handwriting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W4cfuvwsg0. The ressources on the web are endless.